# What is default size of ZipEntry

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

If I create a ZipEntry without specifying it's size, what is default size? Do I need to specify it's size? When do we set the size? I see that ZipEntry has a setSize(long size) method.

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consult the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getSize--

> public long getSize() 
>   Returns the uncompressed size of the entry data.
>   Returns: the uncompressed size of the entry data, or -1 if not known

Or just call getSize() yourself and print out its value.